# log4j2 configure output file for debug level and console for info

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

This is my configuration file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="MyFile" fileName="file.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger level="debug" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"></AppenderRef>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

How can I change it for:

- output the messages with info level in console
- output to file.debug all the messages with debug level

Java:

```
   private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
  logger.info("info");
  logger.debug("debug");
}
```

The problem is that the file is created but it's empty...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="MyFile" fileName="file.log" immediateFlush="true" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="JavaPhit.Log.File" level="DEBUG" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="info"></AppenderRef>
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile" level="debug" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```